# How to Add Some Items In Eclipse Recommender?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

In my Eclipse plugin I want to add some Items to Eclipse recommender so programmers can use them to add some code to project.
how can I do that ?
thank you...

Comment: What do you mean by `Eclipse recommender`?

Comment: @greg-449 hi, for example you  enter jbutton1.s and eclipse recommends you suitable methods like .settext(); it also Appears by ctrl+space...

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how you can contribute your own recommendations.
You may contribute to Eclipse Code Recommenders' code completion by registering a so-called "completion session processor" OR you may contribute to Recommenders API docs view by adding your own "documentation provider". See http://eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/ for the different mechanisms currently available.

For a detailed discussion of what you need, it certainly is more useful to contact the developer mailing list recommenders-dev@eclipse.org or discuss your needs at http://www.codetrails.com/community-forums.